# Monitoring application usage of a computer with many users?

Tags: windows, monitoring

I have a server running Windows in a domain which is accessed by many users and acts as a PC. It has more than 10 sessions at the same time.

I'm hoping to figure out what applications are most used by the users, and get rid of some we rarely use.

Are you familiar with a way to gather application usage information of all the users connected?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend configuring Windows 7 Parential controls - This can be setup to log what is being used on the machine.

http://www.techtalkz.com/windows-7/516005-how-configure-parental-controls-windows-7-a.html

There are packages for Windows XP as well - but you have not defined what OS version you are using.

Comment: Do all the users login with the same credentials? If so then the controls could be installed in that session. By session I assume that you are using Terminal Services?

Comment: Thanks for the response. It is Windows Server 2003. The users login with their own domain username and password using termianl services.